# Why does an email address as a url parameter sometimes not match its corresponding record in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, email

I'm working on an application that has a public registration form that sends an account activation link via email. This link includes a hash signature and an email address, like so:

```
https://example.com/activate.php?email=example%40example.com&signature=a74131ac929229f5803999510a5f4a2a
```

This link is included in the body of an html email template. The hyperlink is built like this:

```
    $encoded_email = url_encode($email);
    $url = "https://example.com/activate.php?email={$encoded_email}&signature={$signature}";
    $body .= <<<HTML 
       <p>Use this link to activate your account</p>
       <p><a href="{$url}">{$url}</a></p>
HTML;
```

When the url is hit, it looks up the registration details and key it needs to verify the signature based on the email address. It works most of the time, but sometimes, the query returns no registration details. The email parameter in the link is somehow not always matching the one stored in mysql.

```
dal::query(
      "select 
         secret, 
         email 
      from 
         registration_details 
      where 
         email = ?", $_GET["email"]
 );
```

Are email clients messing with the email parameter in my link? Any help would be appreciated.

I realize more logging may help me troubleshoot this, but I'm not there yet.

Comment: Are you encoding the email address in the database as well? %40 != @ if you're doing a SQL query.

Comment: @Mark No. However, I don't think that is the issue because in this example $_GET["email"] is url_decoded. Plus, the query works most of the time.

Comment: Do you have examples for when it doesn't work? It looks like it's some encoding weirdness, probably caused by collation in the database?

Comment: @Mark I think you're probably right. I'm in the process of adding some more detailed logging to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: @bingo Did you solve this?

Comment: @Mark no but I hooked up some more detailed logging so I should be able to get to the bottom of it

Comment: @Bingo I would be interested in hearing about the solution when you find one, or helping you find one if you post up some more info about what's going on. My advice would be to dump the SQL after sticking in the email address and see what you are getting.